# Differences in whether realization of a lazy sequence inside of a lazy sequence occurs

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I wondered: What happens when you embed an expression that forces realization of a lazy sequence inside of an outer lazy sequence that's not realized?

Answer: It seems to depend on how you create the outer lazy sequence.  If the outer sequence comes from `map`, the inner sequence is realized, and if the outer sequence comes for `iterate`, it's not.

Well, I'm pretty sure that that is not the right way to describe what happens below--I'm pretty sure that I'm not understanding something.  Can someone explain?

(There is one quirk, which is that while `map` returns a `LazySeq`, `iterate` returns a `Cons` wrapped around a `LazySeq`.  So in the tests for class and realization below, I look at the `rest` of the output of `iterate`.  I don't believe that this difference between `map` and `iterate` has anything to do with my question.)

```
(def three-vec (range 1 4))

(defn print-times-10-ret [x]
  (let [y (* 10 x)] 
    (println "[" y "] " ) 
    y))

(defn once [xs] (map print-times-10-ret xs))

(defn doall-once [xs] (doall (map print-times-10-ret xs)))

(defn doa-twice [xs] (once (doall-once xs))) ; "doa" since only half doall-ed

;; Here the inner sequence seems to get realized:
(def doa-twice-map (doa-twice three-vec))
; printed output:
; [ 10 ]
; [ 20 ]
; [ 30 ]

;; Here we create a lazy sequence that will call doall-once when
;; realized, but nothing gets realized:
(def doall-once-iter (iterate doall-once three-vec))
; no printed output

(class doa-twice-map)
; => clojure.lang.LazySeq

;; Note that this is not realized, even though the inner seq was realized (?):
(realized? doa-twice-map)
; => false

(class (rest doall-once-iter))
; => clojure.lang.LazySeq

(realized? (rest doall-once-iter))
; => false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### *"What happens when you embed an expression that forces realization of a lazy sequence inside of an outer lazy sequence that's not realized?"*

If the expression which forces the realization of the inner sequence is in the unrealized portion of the outer sequence, then nothing.

#### "*Answer: It seems to depend on how you create the outer lazy sequence. If the outer sequence comes from map, the inner sequence is realized, and if the outer sequence comes for iterate, it's not.*"

No, it only depends on whether your forcing expression is in the unrealized portion. Neither `map` nor `iterate` realize anything that isn't already realized.

#### *"describe what happens below"*

You need to think through the [evaluation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) rules. The behavior of your examples is mainly a consequence of eager vs. lazy evaluation (Clojure is eager) and is only tangentially related to lazy sequences.

**First example**

First consider the form

```
(def doa-twice-map (doa-twice three-vec))
```

The first element `def` indicates a special form, with [special evaluation](http://clojure.org/special_forms) rules, but in particular when a second argument is supplied it is evaluated. In particular, you are evaluating

```
(doa-twice three-vec)
```

The evaluation of this form is an invocation of `doa-twice` on `three-vec`, which looks like the following (after substitution)

```
(once (doall-once three-vec)))
```

To evaluate this form, the arguments have to be evaluated first (Clojure does eager evaluation). In particular, you are evaluating

```
(doall-once three-vec)
```

And your `doall-once` is invoked with argument `three-vec`. Now you are evaluating

```
(doall (map print-times-10-ret three-vec))
```

This invokes `doall` on the argument, which is first evaluated to create a lazy-sequence. The `doall` forces realization of that lazy-sequence by definition. During that realization you are invoking `print-times-10-ret` on successive elements of `three-vec`, forcing realization of it along the way.

So the behavior your are seeing here is the consequence of the chaining of the eager evaluation. Eager vs lazy evaluation (Clojure is eager) is not to be confused with lazy vs. non-lazy sequences (Clojure has both).

**Second Example**

When you evaluate the special `def` form

```
(def doall-once-iter (iterate doall-once three-vec))
```

This causes evaluation of the second argument

```
(iterate doall-once three-vec)
```

Evaluation of this form invokes `iterate` on its arguments. Iterate creates a `Cons`-cell of `three-vec` and a lazy-sequence. That `Cons`-cell which is the result of the evaluation is a *value*, thus ending the descent of the chaining of eager evaluation here. This value is set as root binding of a `doall-once-iter` var by the `def`. This is the end of the evaluation of the `def` form.

#### The Parenthetical

*"(There is one quirk, which is that while map returns a LazySeq, iterate returns a Cons wrapped around a LazySeq. So in the tests for class and realization below, I look at the rest of the output of iterate. I don't believe that this difference between map and iterate has anything to do with my question.)"*

Correct, this does not play a role. If `iterate` returned a `LazySeq` object it would still be a *value* and stop the descent of the evaluation chain as above.

See also [count-realized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21950175/1756702) for how to count the realized/non-lazy portion of a sequence without forcing realization. Or, [seq-realized?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/5rwZA-Bzp9A/dgChQhbeF_AJ) in response to what I think is also your question on the Clojure Google Group.

Comment: Thanks for providing such a detailed answer. I had to read through it a couple of times to clear away the confusion I knew I had, but now think the essential point is: I'm passing the function `doall-once` as an argument to `iterate`, and since `iterate` won't call that function until part of the sequence is realized, there's no output.  Whereas in the definition of `doa-twice`, there is actually an application of `doall-once`, and the rest of what happens follows from that fact.  (If this all seems correct, no need to respond.)  Yes, right, that is me over on the Google group.

Comment: (I did understand evaluation, btw, but, clearly, my confusion about lazy sequences drove sense out of me, and I'm glad that you ran through the details.)