# Get all realized values from a lazy seq

Tags: clojure

```
;; create lazy infinite seq of random ints
(def infi-seq (repeatedly #(rand-int 11)))
(take 5 infi-seq) ; => (8 2 9 9 5)
```

How can I get all values realized `(8 2 9 9 2)` without knowing that the first five values have been realized?

Comment: Do you want to generate a list of 5 random values every time? "without knowing that the first five values have been realized" what do you mean?

Comment: @Mark I don't want to generate a list of 5 random values every time. `infi-seq` defers evaluations of its expressions until they are needed. In this case five expressions are evaluated and the values cached. The rest of `infi-seq` is unevaluated until needed. I want to get all the evaluated/cached(realized) values of `infi-seq`. I hope that was a passable explanation.

Comment: Yes, now it's clear. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(defn take-realized
  [coll]
  (if-not (instance? clojure.lang.IPending coll)
    (cons (first coll) (take-realized (rest coll)))
    (when (realized? coll)
       (cons (first coll) (take-realized (rest coll))))))
```

Comment: Sometimes fails: `(take-realized [0 1 2 3 4])` produces `ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPending`. A defect in chunking?

Comment: What's the purpose of `lazy-seq` here as it seems to work without it?

Comment: @Thumbnail Perhaps `realized?` only takes deferred values?

Comment: Right, `realized?` only works on instances of IPending. Thus `(take-realized (iterate inc 1))` would also fail due to `iterate` consing the first element without a `lazy-seq` wrapper.

Comment: @deadghost I think it's a defect in `realized?`, which purportedly *Returns true if a value has been produced for a promise, delay, future or lazy sequence*. As [A.Webb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25532104/1562315) takes account of, it explodes with anything other than a `clojure.lang.IPending` argument.

Comment: I thought you wanted this only for lazy seqs. I added a check for the IPending, but as A. Webb points out it will not work for iterate

Comment: Note quite there yet, now `(take-realized (iterate inc 1))` is going to return the entire lazy sequence. Iterate is a bit of an odd-ball debated a bit on a [related question on the Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/5rwZA-Bzp9A/dgChQhbeF_AJ).

Comment: Overflows with `(take-realized [0 1 2 3 4])` as there's no terminating condition in the event that `coll` is not `clojure.lang.IPending` but as is it answers my question as I only wanted values from a lazy seq.

Comment: @deadghost You can add a `seq` test and recast the code as follows: `(defn take-realized [coll]
  (let [test (if (instance? clojure.lang.IPending coll) realized? seq)]
    (when (test coll)
      (cons (first coll) (take-realized (rest coll))))))`

Comment: @Thumbnail That won't quite work for lazy-sequences that terminate. `(take-realized (doall (repeat 5 5))) ;=> (5 5 5 5 5 nil)`.

Comment: @A.Webb Yes. You explained this for your own `count-realized`. The comment both inadequately repairs the logic and recasts the code: better kept apart.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify or use [count-realized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21950175/1756702)

```
(defn count-realized [s] 
  (loop [s s, n 0] 
    (if (instance? clojure.lang.IPending s)
      (if (and (realized? s) (seq s))
        (recur (rest s) (inc n))
        n)
      (if (seq s)
        (recur (rest s) (inc n))
        n))))
```

Note the check for IPending is necessary for cases where non-lazy elements prepend the sequence, as in iterate.

---

```
(def foo (iterate inc 1))

(take (count-realized foo) foo)
;=> (1)

(dorun (take 5 foo))
;=> nil

(take (count-realized foo) foo)
;=> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: Do you have to check `realized?` before `seq` for a `clojure.lang.IPending` because `seq` might have (and, in the case of `iterate`, does have) the side effect of realizing its argument?

Comment: @Thumbnail Right, `seq` forces realization. There is no way to check a lazy-sequence for emptiness without realizing a possible first element.

Comment: Is the `seq` test necessary? If it's realized, it has an element. dAni's answer induced this thought.

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes, it is necessary. No, a realized sequence does not necessarily have an element. Lazy sequences that terminate do so with an empty tail. `(let [bar (doall (lazy-seq nil))] ((juxt realized? empty?) bar)) ;=> [true true]`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
(defn take-realized [coll]
  (map first (take-while realized? (iterate rest coll))))
```

---

Neat but meretricious. It can be fixed to some extent:

```
(defn take-realized [coll]
  (->> coll
       (iterate next)
       (take-while #(and % (or (not (instance? clojure.lang.IPending %)) (realized? %))))
       (map first)))
```

But this still produces an infinite lazy sequence with `iterate`:

```
(take 5 (take-realized (iterate inc 0)))
;(0 1 2 3 4)
```

The other answers are superior.